# How can I iterate through characters in a SQL result value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have a job table that includes ID and title, something like this:

```
JobID | JobTitle
1       president
2       vice-president
3       director
```

The user table includes a jobID that is supposed to map to the job table, but whoever coded it made it a multi-select field in the UI and appended values with pipes between.  So a user could be a president AND a vice-president AND a director.  Here is an example of the user table

```
UserName | JobID
Suzy       1|2|3
Bob        3
Jane       2|1
```

I'm trying to run a report of all staff and their titles, but am stumped at how to iterate through the multi-value jobIDs and display the jobTitle.

The query I'm currently using is something like:

```
select user.username, job.JobTitle 
from user 
inner join job on user.JobID = job.JobID
```

This is all on SQL Server 2012

Any suggestions?
I'd settle for displaying additional titles on subsequent rows, or in subsequent columns, whatever is easier.

Comment: If at all possible, find the original coder and give them a good backhand while yelling "One to many means header and detail table structure!"  Next, since it is on you to fix it, I hope it is for the sake of fixing the data, because any answer to this will be a kludge and perform like hell.  That's okay, if it's a "run once and done" thing to create insert statements into a proper detail table, but be very wary if you intend to put the answer into use in a production environment as something to be re-executed over and over.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? There are some functions in certain RDBMS's like Teradata's `strtok_split_to_table` or Postgres `unnest(split_to_array())` that would be helpful.

Comment: another way to do it would be like this : `WHERE ('|'+JobID+'|') LIKE('%|3|%')`. Syntax obviously depends on DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is obviously to simply split the column and create a separate table with 1 row per child (job) to have [atomic data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/what-is-atomic-relation-in-first-normal-form). But in the meantime, you can do something like :

```
SELECT [user].username, [job].JobTitle
FROM [job]
INNER JOIN [user] 
    ON ('|'+[user].JobID+'|' LIKE('%|'+CAST([job].JobID as varchar(20))+'|%'))
```

Oh, and before you shout after someone for inserting non-atomic data in a table, start by shunning him for using reserved keywords as table names. Never *ever* **ever** ***ever*** name your table `user`.

---

Btw, this syntax can be used to do something like :

```
CREATE TABLE users AS
SELECT user.username, job.jobId
FROM [job]
INNER JOIN [user] 
    ON ('|'+[user].JobID+'|' LIKE('%|'+CAST([job].JobID as varchar(20))+'|%'))
```

which will net you a sanitized atomic table.

Comment: This is actually a snippet I saw on a similar question like a week ago, I sadly cannot give credits where it's due since I can't recall what question it was.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you can use to split a delimited field and return the results to a table (which you can then use in subsequent operations):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGENSplitDelimField (
    @InputString nvarchar(max),
    @Delimiter nvarchar(10)
)

RETURNS @Results TABLE (
    Item nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

-- default delimiter to comma if blank
IF ISNULL(@Delimiter,'') = ''
BEGIN
    SET @Delimiter = ','
END

DECLARE @Item nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @ItemList nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @DelimIndex int;

SET @ItemList = @InputString
SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)

/*
Loop through all items, removing the first at each iteration.  For example, if we start with the string 'bob,mary,joe':
    1. set @Item = 'bob'
    2. insert 'bob' into result table
    3. set @ItemList = 'mary,joe'
    4. set @DelimIndex = 4
    loop
*/
WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
    INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (@Item)

    -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
    SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
    SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
END -- End WHILE

IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString, and we need to insert the final item in the list
BEGIN
    SET @Item = @ItemList
    INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (@Item)
END
ELSE -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (@InputString)
END

RETURN;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to return a comma separated list of Job titles for each user you can adapt Julien's code, as below:

```
SELECT 
    U2.UserName, 
    SUBSTRING(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                        (
                        SELECT J.JobTitle
                        FROM [job] J
                        INNER JOIN [user] U
                        ON ('|'+U.JobID+'|' LIKE('%|'+CAST(J.JobID as varchar(20))+'|%'))
                        WHERE U.UserName = U2.UserName
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), '</JobTitle>', ''
                    ), '<JobTitle>', ', '
                ),2,1000
            ) [JobTitles]
FROM [user] U2
```